# If an inner class has a function with the same name as an outer class, is it hiding overriding or overloading in C++ and Java?

Tags: java, c++, nested-class

If an inner class has a function with the same name as an outer class, is it hiding overriding or overloading?

I'm talking about situations like this for example (local class):

```
class A{
    void f(){
        class B{
            void g(){..}
            ...
        }
    }
    void g() {...}
}
```

I can't seem to find the answer to this.

Could you please point out if there is a difference in the answer between anonymous, static, inner and local classes?

What's the answer to this question regarding nested classes in C++?

Comment: You're asking 8+ questions packed into one.  I'm willing to bet that everyone one of these questions is already covered on SO.  Search on SO or google, or come up with a more refined question.

Answer (score 2):

In case of Java the answer is **hiding** in all cases you named.
However, you still could access outer method from inner context with that syntax: `A.this.g()`.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: I've just noticed that the question is asking about two very different languages. This answer only covers C++; I've no idea whether or not any of it applies to Java.

> is it hiding overriding or overloading?

It's *hiding*: you're declaring something in an inner scope with the same name as something in an outer scope. The name in the outer scope is no longer accessible via unqualified lookup, although it is accessible as the qualified name `A::g`.

*Overriding* happens (in addition to hiding) when a derived class declares a function with the same name and compatible parameters as a virtual function in the base class.

*Overloading* happens when you declare more than one function with the same name (but different parameters) in the same scope.

> Could you please point out if there is a difference in the answer between anonymous, static, inner and local classes?

There's no difference (and also no such thing as a "static class" in C++). All classes introduce their own scope, inside whatever scope they're declared in.

> What's the answer to this question regarding nested classes in C++?

Exactly the same. The nested class is scoped inside the outer class, and names declared there will hide names in the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

> If an inner class has a function with the same name as an outer class, is it hiding overriding or overloading?

When you define something in a nest scope which is otherwise in an outer scope, this is hiding.

> Could you please point out if there is a difference in the answer between anonymous, static, inner and local classes?

It is purely based on scoping rules.  A simpler example is

```
private final int i;

public void method() {
   long i = 1234; // local variable `i` hides the field.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hiding unless the nested class extends the outer class, in which case it is overriding, in both languages. Anonymous/static/local doesn't make any difference.